# minimize data transfers (use device memory?)

Tags: cuda

I am using a cu file in which I am generating random numbers.

```
...
__global__ void kernel(double* A,double *B, curandState* globalState,int Asize,int Bsize)
{...



void kernel_wrapper(double** A_host,double** B_host, int Asize ,int Bsize)
{

    int N=1000; // random numbers

    //create random states  
    curandState* devStates;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&devStates,N*sizeof(curandState)));


    //allocate host memory 
    *A_host=(double*)malloc(Asize*sizeof(double));
    *B_host=(double*)malloc(Bsize*sizeof(double));


    //allocate device memory
    double* A_dev,*B_dev;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**) &A_dev,Asize* sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**) &B_dev,Bsize* sizeof(double)));


     // setup seeds
    setup_kernel<<<1,N>>>(devStates,unsigned(time(NULL)));
    gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() ); 
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

    //define threads  and blocks
    const int NUM_BLOCKS=16;    
    const int NUM_THREADS=256;  
    dim3 dimGrid(NUM_BLOCKS);
    dim3 dimBlock(NUM_THREADS);

    //generate random numbers
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(A_dev,B_dev,devStates,Asize,Bsize);
    gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

    // copy result from device to host
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(*A_host, A_dev,Asize* sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(*B_host, B_dev,Bsize* sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


    //clean up device memory
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(A_dev));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(B_dev));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(devStates));


}
```

Then ,I am loading these values from a cpp file and use them as an argument to a function.

```
...
extern void kernel_wrapper(double** A,double** B, int Asize ,int Bsize);
...
int main()
{
...
kernel_wrapper(&A,&B,Asize ,Bsize);
...
myfunction(...A,B)
...
 free(A);
 free(B);
```

How can I minimize data transfers and have the work done mostly in device ?
Because right now I am allocating host memory and pass it to cpp file.
I can't figure how to pass the device memory?

Comment: If all you are doing is generating random numbers on the device, and then using them in host code (`myfunction`), you won't be able to do any better than what you've got in terms of passing the data.  Your `myfunction`, being in a .cpp file, is written to use host code, presumably, and so there is no point passing data to it that resides on the device.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Hmm..I guess you have right.The only possibility I can try if I can call the function from inside cu file..

Comment: @Robert Crovella:I opened a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064072/how-to-use-the-cula-device  .I want to use device memory but I am not sure how to pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are doing is generating random numbers on the device, and then using them in host code (`myfunction`), you won't be able to do any better than what you've got in terms of passing the data. Your `myfunction`, being in a `.cpp` file, is written to use host code, presumably, and so there is no point passing data to it that resides on the device.